# CSS на мобильной версии сайта. Ошибка

Tags: css, адаптивность

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь перенести сайт с конструктора на хостин, все вроде скопировал, немного видоизменил но возникла проблема, с боковым меню. Оно на мобильной версии должно прятаться, что почему-то не хочет делать. Уже з десяток раз проверял код и CSS и HTML вроде все идентично как на сайте источнике но работает некорректно.
Собственно сами пациенты: 
http://consaltbuhservis.ru/ оригинал
http://fix.webcredit.info/ на хостинге

Помогите найти в чем ошибка, может свежим взглядом получится найти... башка уже закипает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну так пропишите стиль для этого. Вы забыли взять этот кусок

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .header-main, .footer, .sidebar, #widget-gotop, #widget-callback, #widget-feedback {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Вообще, просто посмотрите, почему там скрывается меню, а не то, что вы не скопировали

Comment: Вы мой спаситель! Спасибо большое! Очень помогли!